# Migrating d3.v3 to d3.v4 in circle force layout chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have following circle force layout chart code using d3.v3 version.,It is working fine.
how to modify version 3 to version 4 using following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>bubble</title>
<style>
.domain {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .3;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
.halo {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
.tick {
 font-size: 10px;
}
.selecting circle {
  fill-opacity: .2;
}

.selecting circle.selected {
  stroke: #f00;
}
.handle {
 fill: #fff;
 stroke: #000;
 stroke-opacity: .5;
 stroke-width: 1.25px;
 cursor: crosshair;
}
</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="nodeCount"></p>
<script>
function draw_bble(){
    var width = 700,
  height = 600,
  padding = 20;
  
 var start = new Date(2013,0,1),
  end = new Date(2013,11,31)

 var data = []
 
 for (i=0; i < 80; i++) {
  var point = {}
  
  var year = 2013;
  var month = Math.floor(Math.random()*12)
  var day = Math.floor(Math.random()*28)
  
  point.date = new Date(year, month, day)
  point.mIndex = i
  point.impact=Math.floor(Math.random()*80)
  data.push(point)  
 }
 console.log(data)
      var color = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([d3.min(data, function(d){ return d.impact; }), (d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.impact; })-d3.min(data, function(d){ return d.impact; }))/2, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.impact; })])
          .range(["red","#FFFF55","green"]);
 var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))
  .size([width - padding, height - 100])
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start()
 
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr({
   "width": width,
   "height": height
  }) 
 
 //build stuff
 var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([start, end])
  .range([padding, width - 6*padding])
  .clamp(true) 
 
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .tickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(20)
  //.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%x")) 
   
 //manipulate stuff
 d3.selectAll(".resize").append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("fill", "Red")
  .classed("handle", true)
 
 d3.select(".domain")
  .select(function() {return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true))})
  .classed("halo", true)

 function tick() {
  var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.mIndex; })
  
  nodes
   .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x})
   .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y})
   
  nodes
   .enter()
                .append("circle")
       .attr("r", 10)
       .attr("fill",function(d){ return color(d.impact)})
       .call(force.drag)
       .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y})
    .style("stroke","#000")
                .style("stroke-width","1px")

  nodes
   .exit()
    .remove()
 }
}
draw_bble();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of d3.v3 version I have to use latest d3.v4 version.
Is it possible change the version using version 3 code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the necessary changes:

```
var color = d3.scaleLinear()
```

Instead of `scale.linear()`.

And for the force:

```
var force = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(12))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .nodes(data)
    .on("tick", tick);
```

Here is a demo with the "enter" selection (which I moved outside the `tick` function, besides removing all code that doesn't matter for the force):

```js
function draw_bble() {
    var width = 500,
        height = 400,
        padding = 20;

    var start = new Date(2013, 0, 1),
        end = new Date(2013, 11, 31)

    var data = []

    for (i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        var point = {}

        var year = 2013;
        var month = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)
        var day = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28)

        point.date = new Date(year, month, day)
        point.mIndex = i
        point.impact = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80)
        data.push(point)
    }

    var color = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {
            return d.impact;
        }), (d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return d.impact;
        }) - d3.min(data, function(d) {
            return d.impact;
        })) / 2, d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return d.impact;
        })])
        .range(["red", "#FFFF55", "green"]);

    var force = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(12))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
        .nodes(data)
        .on("tick", tick);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(data, function(d) {
            return d.mIndex;
        }).enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.impact)
        })
        .style("stroke", "#000")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px");

    function tick() {

        nodes.attr("cx", function(d) {
                return d.x
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return d.y
            })
    }
}
draw_bble();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```