# d3v4 bubble chart update

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

[image]

I've got an old d3v3 bubble chart -- it had some animation aspects -- I am trying to upgrade it to a v4

//version 3
https://jsfiddle.net/497tmhu0/

There is always a desire to have some animation for when these bubbles load for the first time.

So here - bubbles are created very small and then they expand in size to their resting size.

```
        // Enter
        nodes.enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
            .attr("r", 10)
            .style("fill", function (d, i) { 
              return color(i);
            })
            .call(force.drag());

        // Update
        nodes
            .transition()
            .delay(300)
            .duration(1000)
              .attr("r", function (d) { 
                return d.radius * scale; 
              })

        // Exit
        nodes.exit()
            .transition()
            .duration(250)
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
            .attr("r", 1)
            .remove();
```

I was converting the chart but some parts of the force functions are no longer working.

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048
https://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/e6209de87cdddde38dadbb746feaf3a3

this is the current v4 I have - but the animation and force parts are broken.
//current version 4
https://jsfiddle.net/497tmhu0/2/

---

June 8th -- bubbles grow in size now -- but force aspects are not working - https://jsfiddle.net/vkoxrtwz/ - need to give the bubbles some force aspects - and if clicked on temporarily change their charge so it ripples through the chart and causes the circles to repel/attract each other slightly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41341248/migrating-d3-v3-to-d3-v4-in-circle-force-layout-chart

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992772/bubbles-disappeared-after-converting-d3v3-to-d3v4

Comment: keen to get this chart fixed -- resolve the animation and force parts of the bubbles -- make it stable

Answer (score 4):

You can just chain your animations after the first enter() method. Draw them small, and then add a transition immediately.

```
  // Enter
    nodes.enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("r", 1)
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      })
      .transition()
      .delay(300)
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.radius * scale;
      })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vkoxrtwz/

Comment: ah I see you fixed the update part -- but the ".call(d3.drag());" doesn't get invoked - its got no force aspect to it - where the bubbles drift a little and continue to react to each like gravity/repel aspects

Comment: and also clicking on the bubbles you'd maybe want it to react - like as if its electric property had changed and the user had given it a charge difference and again this caused ALL bubbles to respond a little

Comment: Do you have an example of it working properly? I'm not sure what it's supposed to do. It doesn't seem to move at all in the v3 version you provided.

Comment: yeah it doesn't really move about a lot in v3 - on reload you can see the bubbles float a little - and when you tap on them they jolt -- but I believe the force aspects are in affect here - if not a bit malfunctioned

Comment: you able to fix the force aspects so I can award the bounty

Comment: Really need to fix the force aspects

Comment: able to fix the force aspects for 200 bounty?

Comment: hi @georgedum you able to fix the force aspects